# A question in Proof of Theorem 10.27 of Apostol Mathematical Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

While self studying Lebesgue integration from Tom M Apostol I am unable to think about an how to deduce a line in the proof whose image I am adding( line is highlited.

[image]

> I am not able to deduce the line that the sequence { $G_n(x) $ } decreases almost everywhere and hence converges everywhere.

I am unable to get how the author wrote that {$ G_n (x) $ } is decreasing? and how that implies that it's convergent.

Kindly help.

Comment: The fact $G_n(x) $ is decreasing is already explained in "since $A\subseteq B$ implies $\sup A \leq \sup B$".

Comment: The convergence of $G_n(x) $ is explained afterwards by showing that if $f_n(x) \to f(x) $ then $G_n(x) \to f(x) $. The details are in next page of the book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\{G_n (x)\}$ is decreasing because it's defined as supremum of $\{f_n(x), f_{n+1}(x),...\}$. $G_1 (x)=\sup\{f_1(x),f_2(x),f_3(x),...\}$ and $G_2(x)=\sup\{f_2(x), f_3(x),...\}$, so, depending on $f_1(x)$, $G_2(x)\leq G_1(x)$ and so on.
And this is why $\{G_n (x)\}$ converges a.e.: $\{f_n(x)\}$ converges a.e. and for fixed $x_0$, such that number sequence $\{f_n(x_0)\}$ converges, we have $$\lim_{n\to \infty}f_n(x_0) = \lim_{n\to \infty}\left( \sup_{m\geq n}f_n(x_0)\right) = \lim_{n\to \infty}\left( \inf_{m\geq n}f_n(x_0)\right)$$
So, $$\lim_{n\to \infty}f_n(x_0) = \lim_{n\to \infty}G_n(x_0)$$ hence $\{G_n (x)\}$ converges in points, where $\{f_n (x)\}$ also converges.